# Centering form with flex rows

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a form where every single row has `display: flex`. Each row has a label box with a fixed width and a field box which fit to his content. Now it looks like this:

[image]

What I want to achive is to shrink every row to the minimum content width and centering the form horizontally. Something like this:

[image]

I tried using `inline-flex` for rows but seems like parent becomes smaller than the total width of children.

Is there a way to achive it keeping flexbox for each row and without using `transform: translate` to align form horizontally?

Here is the code of the first image:

```css
.form-container {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.form {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
}


.form-row {
  display: flex;
  background-color: silver;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.form-row-label {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.form-row-field {
  flex: 0 1 0;
  background-color: orangered;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
  <div class="form">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-row-label">
        label 1
      </div>
      <div class="form-row-field">
        field 1 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-row-label">
        label 2
      </div>
      <div class="form-row-field">
        field 2 xxxx
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-row-label">
        label 3
      </div>
      <div class="form-row-field">
        field 3 xxxxxxxxxx
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzu9zvje/19/).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea:

```css
.form-container {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-align:center; /* Center the inline-block*/
}

.form {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
  display:inline-block; /* Use this to fit content */
}

.form-row {
  display: flex;
  background-color: silver;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.form-row-label {
  width: 200px;
  flex-shrink:0; /* Avoid the content to shrink*/
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  text-align:left;
}

.form-row-field {
  flex-shrink:0;
  background-color: orangered;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
  <div class="form">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-row-label">
        label 1
      </div>
      <div class="form-row-field">
        field 1 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-row-label">
        label 2
      </div>
      <div class="form-row-field">
        field 2 xxxx
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-row-label">
        label 333
      </div>
      <div class="form-row-field">
        field 3 xxxxxxxxxx
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the best solution, Why `flex: 0 0 200px` doesn't work as `width: 200px`? Which is the difference?

Comment: @Fabio it's because of the inline-bloc that make the width fit the content and then the flex-basis is based on this width ...so if you try for example flex-basis:100% you will have the blue part cover all the yellow part.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea using `display:inline-flex` and `flex-direction:column` in the `.form` class with `text-align: center` in the parent class. Also you will need to use `width: 200px` in `label` instead of `flex-basis:200px`

```css
.form-container {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.form {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.form-row {
  display: flex;
  background-color: silver;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.form-row-label {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.form-row-field {
  flex: 0 1 0;
  background-color: orangered;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
  <div class="form">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-row-label">
        label 1
      </div>
      <div class="form-row-field">
        field 1 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-row-label">
        label 2
      </div>
      <div class="form-row-field">
        field 2 xxxx
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-row-label">
        label 3
      </div>
      <div class="form-row-field">
        field 3 xxxxxxxxxx
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the yellow box within the black box, you should only add below code to your code:

```
.form {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
    width: 650px;
    max-width: 650px;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.form-row-label {
   flex: 0 0 60%;
   background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

I think it will help you a little bit.

Comment: can you explain the 650px ?

Comment: the width is used as approx. here we can use the width %(percentage).